# SQLRPGLE issue compiling with dcl-s xml_data SQLTYPE(CLOB:10000000);

Tags: clob

Up until the latest PTFs were applied to our iSeries I was able to compile RPG programs that used sqltype clob and clob_file (ex dcl-s xml_data  SQLTYPE(CLOB:10000000);)
now I get the compile time error RNF3308 20 a      001001+ Keyword name is not valid; the keyword is ignored.
Anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

solved issue.  Looks like one of our compile options was changes or reverted after a ptf was applied.  needed to set RPGPPOPT(*LVL2) in compile.